# Multiple DAG generation while syncing on testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, dag

While blockchain synchronisation on testnet, I see multiple DAG generation messages along with the percentage of DAG generated?

After this when I check the `eth.syncing` output my value of `currentBlock` has gone down from 477000 to nearly 400000 and also geth exited.

I am attaching images for the DAG messages as well as the message occurred when geth exited?

[image: screenshot of dag]

[image: screenshot of crash]

What is wrong here?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the first question: It's generating the DAG because you probably started a mining thread.